# Understanding program organisation and basic terms

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I've installed Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.2 in order to edit a couple of existing Jasper reports. Unless I missed something, nowhere in *Getting Started* documentation do they explain the basic terms specific to this program. They do explain the generic Jasper terms (report, data adapter, field...) but, when it comes to Jaspersoft Studio, they just instruct you to launch wizards and use the defaults. That isn't optimal for me because I prefer to have my work under source control and separated by customer/client rather than having everything together in a local folder within my Windows profile. I also have the impression that they omit stuff because they assume you're familiar with Eclipse (I'm not).

Could you please provide me with a quick overview of the basic terms and some tips about how to use them to effectively organise work:

- Workspace
- Project
- Project Folder

... and some other I might be missing?

Comment: Of course, I get downvotes every time I ask a question that doesn't have a block of code, even though questions about [Software development tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) are specifically on-topic. *sigh*

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple workspace in Jasper I tried to create another one, because I began to have lot of JasperProjects. If you find how to do it please share it.

Comment: @HamzaInce Yes, you can. Just head to "File /Switch Workspace" and type a new path. However you can only have one workspace open at the same time. (The feature looks similar to what IDEs call "project" but I'm not really sure.)

Answer (score 1):

My view:
A *workspace* is a group projects that share some configuration/environment. In project setting, you can use a common workspace configuration or define a project specific configuration.

In java world, e.g. you can define different JDK compatibility per workspace.

In jasper world, e.g. for Chinese projects, you can have projects that all have zh_CN default language set when executing preview. Different fonts might be used in this workspace. No need to set it up for every new project created.

Every workspace has it's own set of data adapters and JRS server connections.

I usually have sources under "Project folder", not in workspace folder. I just import a project into the workspace (do not copy).

BTW. One project can be in multiple workspaces.